What is the proces of Bhairavi Yatana?
Some followup questions on Bhairavi Yatana:

What is the process in Bhairavi Yatana?
Is there an initiation required?
What are the detailed steps have to be taken?

Where to get more information, please share some references?

You might add some details of the question. It will help other community members.

Refer the following link for Sri Tripura Bhairavī Tantra Sādhana (श्रीत्रिपुरभैरवी तन्त्र साधना).
